# IMCE buttons are missing and cannot delete files

Tags: 7

I'm using the latest version of Filefield Sources and IMCE.

I've set up the profile we're using to be able to do everything they should need to be able to do:

[image]

However, when I try to manage any of the files there I cannot do anything other than upload a new file.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't delete files that are in use (i.e. have records in the file_usage table). Are you sure the files you want to delete are not referenced by other content/entities? And that the web server user has permission to write to the relevant folders?

Comment: I don't even get the buttons at all - regardless of whether or not a file is selected. I'm logged in as user1 in the screenshot above.